# How do modified mob's knockback in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

i really mant to play minecraft with mobs that has 1.000.000 knockbacks, it sounds cool and fun. so **how do i can change mob's knockback?** need third party app to mod the world or just use commands block?

and is it possible to stay on survival while the knockback has changed?, thanks.

Comment: Knockback of a mob's attack or the amount of knockback a mob receives when punched with a fist?

Comment: @aytimothy i think the former.

Comment: So do you want the mob to have an item with knockback, or his data?

Comment: @ayimothy what is the differences?

Answer (score 2):

You could try modifying the entity's `minecraft:generic.attack_knockback` attribute using the `/attribute` command like so:

```
attribute @s minecraft:generic.attack_knockback base set <value>
```

- `<value>` being a number ranging from 0.0 to 5.0

If you wish to use the item method, you could use the `/replaceitem` command to give the entity an item with the knockback enchantment in its mainhand. Here's an example:

```
replaceitem entity <targetEntity> weapon.mainhand minecraft:stick{Enchantments: [{id: "minecraft:knockback", lvl: 1s}]}
```

- `<targetEntity>` being the entity you'll give the item to. This field accepts either UUID, or a target selector. (e.g `@e[type = zombie]`)

Comment: like when the mob attack or fist or explode use this "attribute @s minecraft:generic.attack_knockback base set <value>" ?